# Turn off keep alive in golang

Tags: http, go

I have written a server that will accept about 10k requests a second asynchronously (8 workers), but I have `keep-alive` turned on by default. How do I turn it off? Will `w.Header().Set("Connection", "close")` be enough in a request handler?

Answer (score 0):

http.Server has method [SetKeepAlivesEnabled](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server.SetKeepAlivesEnabled)

```
func ListenAndServeWithKeepAlivesDisabled(addr string, handler http.Handler) error {
    server := &Server{Addr: addr, Handler: handler}
    server.SetKeepAlivesEnabled(false)
    return server.ListenAndServe()
}
```